# Entity-Sql queries with DbContext

Tags: .net, entity-framework, dbcontext, objectcontext

Migrating an Entity Framework project from `ObjectContext` to `DbContext`, I have found no means to execute an E-Sql query string directly with `DbContext`. (Entity-SQL is not SQL, but a SQL like query language, see this [msdn reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb399560%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)).

Previous code was like following [msdn example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb738512%28v=vs.100%29.aspx#_ESQL):

```
using (AdventureWorksEntities context =
    new AdventureWorksEntities())
{
    string myQuery = @"SELECT p.ProductID, p.Name FROM 
        AdventureWorksEntities.Products as p";

    foreach (DbDataRecord rec in
        new ObjectQuery<DbDataRecord>(myQuery, context))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("ID {0}; Name {1}", rec[0], rec[1]);
    }
}
```

(Where `AdventureWorksEntities` is an `ObjectContext`.)

After migration to `DbContext`, we can still execute E-SQL queries by reaching underlying object context like below:

```
using (AdventureWorksEntities context =
    new AdventureWorksEntities())
{
    string myQuery = @"SELECT p.ProductID, p.Name FROM 
        AdventureWorksEntities.Products as p";

    foreach (DbDataRecord rec in
        new ObjectQuery<DbDataRecord>(myQuery,
            ((IObjectContextAdapter)context).ObjectContext))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("ID {0}; Name {1}", rec[0], rec[1]);
    }
}
```

(Where `AdventureWorksEntities` is now a `DbContext`.)

This does work. But since I would rather limit the number of APIs I use, is there a way to execute E-SQL queries directly from a `DbContext` without having to reach explicitly the underlying `ObjectContext`?

(And without using an `ObjectQuery` by the way. I known I could easily convert those examples for using other querying solution like Linq-to-Entity, but my current use case requires for now to works with E-SQL query strings.)

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/data/jj592907

Comment: This link is for raw SQL queries. What is the relation with E-SQL queries?

Comment: Oops, my mistake, didn't spot the difference.